# read data into R with different delimiters

Tags: r, read.table

I am trying to read a file into R that has different delimiters in the first row has space as delimiters but from the 2nd row to the last between the first column and the second there is a space, the same between the second and third, then all the block of two, zeros and ones should be different columns.
any hint?!

```
ID Chip AX-77047182 AX-80910836 AX-80737273 AX-77048714 AX-77048779 AX-77050447 
3811582 1 2002202222200202022020200200220200222200022220002200000201202000222022
3712982 1 2002202222200202022020200200220200222200022220002200000200202000222022
3712990 1 2002202211200202021011100101210200111101022121112100111110211110122122
3713019 1 2002202211200202021011100101210200111101022121112100111110211110122122
3713025 1 2002202211200202021011100101210200111101022121112100111110211110122122
3713126 1 2002202222200202022020200200220200222200022220002200000200202000222022
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example of your expected output?

Comment: sure for the first three rows:  first row: ID Chip AX-77047182 AX-80910836. And second row:  3811582 1 2 0. The separators should be spaces.

Comment: Please edit your post, instead of commenting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly not the most elegant solution, but you could try the following. If I have understood your example data correctly, you have not provided all the column names (AX-77047182,...) that would be needed for the rows of zeros/ones/twos. If my understanding is wrong, below approach will not result in the desired result, but might still aid you in finding a workaround - you might simply adapt the delimiter in the second split command. I hope this helps...

```
#read file as character vector
chipstable <- readLines(".../chips.txt")

#extact first line to be used as column names
tablehead <- unlist(strsplit(chipstable[1], " "))

#split by first delimiter, i.e., space
chipstable <- strsplit(chipstable[2:length(chipstable)], " ")

#split by second delimiter, i.e., between each character (here number) 
#and merge the two split results in one line
chipstable <- lapply(chipstable, function(x) {

  c(x[1:2],  unlist(strsplit(x[3], "")))

})

#combine all lines to a data frame
chipstable <- do.call(rbind, chipstable)

#assign column names
colnames(chipstable) <- tablehead

#turn values to numeric (if needed)
chipstable <- apply(chipstable, 2, as.numeric)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try ... `read(pattern = " || 1 ", recursive = TRUE)`
After make a bind

For instance:

```
data <- "ID Chip AX-77047182 AX-80910836 AX-80737273 AX-77048714 AX-77048779 AX-77050447 
3811582 1 2002202222200202022020200200220200222200022220002200000201202000222022
3712982 1 2002202222200202022020200200220200222200022220002200000200202000222022
3712990 1 2002202211200202021011100101210200111101022121112100111110211110122122
3713019 1 2002202211200202021011100101210200111101022121112100111110211110122122
3713025 1 2002202211200202021011100101210200111101022121112100111110211110122122
3713126 1 2002202222200202022020200200220200222200022220002200000200202000222022"

teste <- strsplit(data, split = "\n")

for(i in seq(1, length(teste[[1]]),1)) {
  if (i==1) {
    dataOut <- strsplit(teste[[1]][i], split = " ")
    print(dataOut)
  } else
    dataOut <- strsplit(teste[[1]][i], split = " 1 ")
  print(dataOut)
}
```